# How to count numbers in a string with php

Tags: php, count

Hi i have an dynamic string like this `5,6,7,8,11,25` in my database. I want to count how much numbers are in the string. In my example there are 6. But I don't find a solution. Please help me.

Comment: What you're looking for is: explode() with comma and then count() or you can use preg_match or any other function, but exploding it into array and then counting an array is simple and easy. Something like this `echo count(explode(',', $result['from_db']));`

Comment: @Amal Murali but I want to count the numbers.

Comment: Why I get such negativ votes?

Comment: I think you misunderstood Stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL lacks an explode function so you have to query the data and do the count in php using `explode()` and `count()`.

```
count(explode(",", $string));
```

The `explode()` function breaks the string into an array element for each string separated by a comma, and then the `count()` function returns the number of elements in that array.

Comment: Yes, except it doesn't count the numbers, it counts the elements.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy This produces the result that you explained in your example. Do you want to count the total number of digits in the entire string (in your example 8), or the total number of comma separated numbers (in your example 6)?

Comment: I am not the OP, but if you look at the question comments, he specifically says count(explode) won't work because he only wants to count the numbers.  So I suspect if the string was a,b,c,1,2,3 he would want to see 3 not 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = explode(',', '5,6,7,8,11,25');
echo count($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

your string

```
$str = '5,6,7,8,11,25';
```

then use explode to convert the string into an array

```
$str_array = explode(',', $str);
```

and to get the number of elements of the array

```
$size = count($str_array);
```

Comment: The `sizeof()` function is generally discouraged in PHP because it is simply an alias of the `count()` function and has a very different meaning in most other c-style languages which can be confusing or lead to ambiguity. Because of this the `count()` function is generally preferred.

Comment: ok thanks you I will change the sizeof() with count()

Answer (score 0):

To count the numbers you will have to use something like:

```
count(array_filter(explode(',', $string), "is_numeric"))
```

But be careful, every string value that looks numeric will be counted.